# HTML p tag not showing

Tags: html, css, article

How is it possible that the p tag is not showing inside a browser:

code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/jquery.fancybox.css" />
      <link rel="icon" href="../img/favicon.png" type="image/png" />

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>    
            <div>
                <a href="../index.html" title="test">
                    <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <article> 
<p>testestest</p>
<p>testestest</p>
<p>testestest</p>
        </article>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A customer told me that the text does not show.
I will ask for the browser she is using, but I do not have any clue why this will not work.

It worked on every browser I used and the HTML validator shows no error nor a warning.
Has anyone a tip?

Comment: the content inside the p  tag is static?

Comment: yes its static just plain text, which I do not want to show here

Comment: Could it be a javascript problem which stop the page loading ?

Comment: Could you upload style.css file or make fiddle?

Comment: Issue has been solved. Customer updated his Browser ( it was a Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Is this due to some IE quirks regarding the HTML5 elements? IE6 is known for generating the wrong DOM for any tagname it does not recognize. The wrong DOM does not treat `<p>` as a child of `<article>`, but something like:

- `<article>`
- `<p>....</p>`
- `</article>`

... where these are three elements at the save level (What?!), with the closing tag `</article>` counts as an element on its own (Wat?!). This can break a bunch of things including your CSS.

In that case, you may want to try [html5shiv](https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv).

Answer (score 0):

The customer may be using IE8 or other outdated browser that does not support the `<article>` tag, causing problems with the `<p>` tags inside it.

The [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp) page on the `<article>` tag lists the earliest browser versions supporting the tag.